# RSS feed script "Connection timed out"

Tags: php, codeigniter, rss, rss-reader

I've a RSS script for a client.
It has worked perfectly for about 1 month. But the other day it suddenly stopped working.

I'm only getting this error after around 15-20 seconds "Connection timed out".

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?
The script is working on localhost where I've tested it earlier today.

I'm using the "rssparser" library together with Codeigniter.

Here is the code:

```
function get_feed($link)
{

    $this->load->helper('text');

    $last_update = time();

    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
    header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
    header('Content-type: application/json');

    // Load RSS Parser
    $this->load->library('rssparser');

    // Get 6 items from arstechnica
    $rss = $this->rssparser->set_feed_url($link)->set_cache_life(30)->getFeed(5);

    foreach ($rss as $item)
    {

        $pubdate = strtotime($item['pubDate']);
        $monthName = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m",$pubdate), 10));
        $new_date = date("d.",$pubdate).' '.$monthName.' '.date("Y",$pubdate).' '.date("H:i",$pubdate);

        $array[] = array(
            'title' => $item['title'],
            'description' => character_limiter($item['description'],100),
            'author' => $item['author'],
            'pubDate' => $new_date,
            'link' => $item['link']
        );
    }

    $array = json_encode($array);

    return $array;
}
```

Hope someone have any idea what is going on.

Comment: Do u use a database?

Comment: Nope - only direct connection

Comment: i think the "Connection timeout error" is raised when it's try to read the external file using ```file_get_contents($this->feed_uri);``` method (line 89 i guess). try using ```curl``` to read the external content.

Comment: You should probably distinguish the "fetching" and the "parsing" part... The fetching can timeout for many reasons.